# Extract multiple pieces of information having optinal fields with RegEx

Tags: php, regex

I would like your help figuring out how to extract this information from a text file. there is a field that is optional (here labeled "S")

The text looks like this:

```
  NAME     Case No. Duration PLAN       ACCT DATE ST DATE A MODE   AMOUNT CRATE S AccountTotal                     
  PETER             AB02651341 RN BUILDER IUL CTAT 02/05/15 02/05/15 01             380.00   0.0050            1.90               
  JOHNSON, DON A BF06010672 FY AGGVANT 15 NT1      02/02/15 02/01/15 01            83.04   0.0500            4.15             
  SARA             ZZ02659940 RN CUST GUAR          01/31/15 01/30/15 12        18,450.00- 0.0025            46.13-            
  MIKE              KH02979366 RN CUST GUAR        02/02/15 02/01/15 01             109.83   0.0025 .50         .14
```

Is it possible to have it outputted as this (in an array or other structure):

```
NAME    Case No.    Duration    PLAN    DATE ST DATE A  MODE    AMOUNT  CRATE   S   AccountTotal
PETER   AB02651341  RN  BUILDER IUL CTAT    02/02/15    02/05/2015  01  380.00  0.0050      1.90
JOHNSON, DON A  BF06010672  FY  AGGVANT 15 NT1  02/2/2015   02/01/15    01  83.04   0.0500      4.15
SARA    ZZ02659940  RN  CUST GUAR   01/31/2015  01/30/2015  12  -18,450.00  0.0025      -46.13
MIKE    KH02979366  RN  CUST GUAR   02/02/15    02/01/2015  01  109.83  0.0025  .50 .14
```

Final output will be something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [NAME] => PETER [Case No.] => AB02651341 [Duration] => RN [PLAN] => BUILDER IUL CTAT [DATE ST] => 02/02/15 [DATE A] => 02/05/2015 [MODE] => 01 [AMOUNT] => 380.00 [CRATE] => 0.0050 [S] => [AccountTotal] => 1.90 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [NAME] => JOHNSON, DON A [Case No.] => BF06010672 [Duration] => FY [PLAN] => AGGVANT 15 NT1 [DATE ST] => 02/2/2015 [DATE A] => 02/01/15 [MODE] => 01 [AMOUNT] => 83.04 [CRATE] => 0.0500 [S] => [AccountTotal] => 4.15 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [NAME] => SARA [Case No.] => ZZ02659940 [Duration] => RN [PLAN] => CUST GUAR [DATE ST] => 01/31/2015 [DATE A] => 01/30/2015 [MODE] => 12 [AMOUNT] => -18,450.00 [CRATE] => 0.0025 [S] => [AccountTotal] => -46.13 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [NAME] => MIKE [Case No.] => KH02979366 [Duration] => RN [PLAN] => CUST GUAR [DATE ST] => 02/02/15 [DATE A] => 02/01/2015 [MODE] => 01 [AMOUNT] => 109.83 [CRATE] => 0.0025 [S] => .50 [AccountTotal] => .14 ) )
```

Comment: How are the fields in the original text delimited?

Comment: this is pdf turned text file, all I have is the spacing as posted above. Everything is just spaced (spacebar) out.

Comment: So how can you tell where the `NAME` field ends and the `CASE No` begins, since the name can have multiple words in it? You need an unambiguous delimiter.

Comment: best I can say is NAME is before Case No. which is defined as 2 letters followed by 8 numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would work?

```
$a = <<<EOT
  NAME     Case No. Duration PLAN       ACCT DATE ST DATE A MODE   AMOUNT CRATE S AccountTotal
  PETER             AB02651341 RN BUILDER IUL CTAT 02/05/15 02/05/15 01             380.00   0.0050            1.90
  JOHNSON, DON A BF06010672 FY AGGVANT 15 NT1      02/02/15 02/01/15 01            83.04   0.0500            4.15
  SARA             ZZ02659940 RN CUST GUAR          01/31/15 01/30/15 12        18,450.00- 0.0025            46.13-
  MIKE              KH02979366 RN CUST GUAR        02/02/15 02/01/15 01             109.83   0.0025 .50         .14
EOT;

$cols = array(
    'NAME'         => '\s+(.*?)',
    'Case No.'     => '\s+(\w\w\d{8})',
    'Duration'     => '\s(\w\w)',
    'PLAN'         => '\s+(.*?)',
    'DATE ST'      => '\s+(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d)',
    'DATE A'       => '\s+(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d)',
    'MODE'         => '\s+(\d\d)',
    'AMOUNT'       => '\s+(\-?.*?)',
    'CRATE'        => '\s+(\d+\.\d+)',
    'S'            => '\s+([\.\d]*)',
    'AccountTotal' => '\s+(\-?.*?)$',
);

$result = array();
foreach (explode(PHP_EOL, $a) as $row) {
    if (preg_match('#' . implode(array_values($cols)) . '#', $row, $matches)) {

        // Move any trailing dash to the front of AMOUNT and
        // AccountTotal (a bit hackish - could be improved :)
        $matches[8]  = preg_replace('/(.*)-$/', '-$1', $matches[8]);
        $matches[11] = preg_replace('/(.*)-$/', '-$1', $matches[11]);

        $result[] = array_combine(array_keys($cols), array_slice($matches, 1));
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => PETER
            [Case No.] => AB02651341
            [Duration] => RN
            [PLAN] => BUILDER IUL CTAT
            [DATE ST] => 02/05/15
            [DATE A] => 02/05/15
            [MODE] => 01
            [AMOUNT] => 380.00
            [CRATE] => 0.0050
            [S] => 
            [AccountTotal] => 1.90
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => JOHNSON, DON A
            [Case No.] => BF06010672
            [Duration] => FY
            [PLAN] => AGGVANT 15 NT1
            [DATE ST] => 02/02/15
            [DATE A] => 02/01/15
            [MODE] => 01
            [AMOUNT] => 83.04
            [CRATE] => 0.0500
            [S] => 
            [AccountTotal] => 4.15
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => SARA
            [Case No.] => ZZ02659940
            [Duration] => RN
            [PLAN] => CUST GUAR
            [DATE ST] => 01/31/15
            [DATE A] => 01/30/15
            [MODE] => 12
            [AMOUNT] => -18,450.00
            [CRATE] => 0.0025
            [S] => 
            [AccountTotal] => -46.13
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => MIKE
            [Case No.] => KH02979366
            [Duration] => RN
            [PLAN] => CUST GUAR
            [DATE ST] => 02/02/15
            [DATE A] => 02/01/15
            [MODE] => 01
            [AMOUNT] => 109.83
            [CRATE] => 0.0025
            [S] => .50
            [AccountTotal] => .14
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `?` after a regexp to indicate that it's optional. So if XXX is the regexp for the earlier part of the line, you can write:

```
preg_match('/^XXX(?:\s+([\d.]+))?\s+([\d.]+)$/', $line, $match);
```

The capture group for the `S` field will be empty when the field isn't supplied.